# Как создать кнопку, чтобы поделиться контактом в aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Этот код выдает ошибку

```
async def contact_kb():
      return ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(KeyboardButton('Отправить свой контакт ☎️', request_contact=True))

@router.message()
async def get_contact(message: types.Message):
    try:
        if False: return
        else:
            await message.answer(get_contact_txt,
                                reply_markup=await contact_kb())
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Пожалуйста подскажите как
это исправить

Ошибка возникает когда отправляешь боту сообщение

```
1 validation error for ReplyKeyboardMarkup
keyboard
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'resize_keyboard': True}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример, а также уточните, где именно возникает ошибка